# Aggregation in mongodb & $group,$project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using aggregation framework. While using $match, if no matches found then I want to get the count in $group. But it is coming 0 element fetches.

Query is like this;

```
{
    $project: {
        totalOffered: "$totalOffered",
        totalOpen: "$totalOpen",
        totalJoined: "$totalJoined",
        totalInter: "$totalInter",
        "reportData": {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$repo", 0]
        },
        "repo": {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$repo", 0]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$reportData"
}, {
    $unwind: "$reportData.candidates"
}, {
    $unwind: "$reportData.candidates.candidateStatus"
}, {
    $match: {
        "reportData.candidates.candidateStatus.status": "Joined"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalCount: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}
```

How to get the count as 0 if no matches found?

Comment: Same question was asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022469/while-using-match-if-no-matches-found-then-i-want-to-get-the-count-in-group, 
Please approve the edit pending for you and share a sample document, if possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While using $match, if no matches found then I want to get the count in $group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022469/while-using-match-if-no-matches-found-then-i-want-to-get-the-count-in-group)